# Django query optimization

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have a model with a lot of entries (more than 12,513,262) and they are supposed to increase exponentially. But the problem is due to this large no. entries querying is taking a lot of time is there a way to increase performance using indices etc.

My query is like this:

```
MyModel.objects.all().order_by('-timestamp')[0:50]
```

and its taking a lot of time to execute.

Comment: excuse me, what is the model name? just curious.

Comment: @Glycerine, of course! Now, I understand why about 12513262 entries ;)

Answer (score 4):

do you have an [index](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#db-index) on the timestamp field?

if you use [south](http://south.aeracode.org/) (for database migrations, you should definitely look into it if you aren't already), you can just add `db_index=True` to your field and migrate. Otherwise you can run

```
./manage.py sqlindexes MyApp
```

to show the sql statement adding the index. (which you need to run manually, e.g. using

```
./manage.py dbshell
```

Comment: i don t have any index yet can i create one now if yes how to do that ?

Comment: If you haven't been using South, you'll need to create the index manually with the appropriate SQL. That will vary based on what DB you're using. Ask Google: "create index [my database brand]"